# how to keep my accelerometer awake with screen off

Tags: android, screen, accelerometer

I've encounter a problem that my accelerometer not work with screen off.
When I turned off the screen, the logcat says tag:"AK8973" with deecription :"compass off "
Is there a way to keep my accelerometer awake when the screen off?
My platform is Android 2.2 with HTC Desire.
Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: It seems that the answer is impossible due to the firmware contraints......

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to keep my accelerometer awake when the screen off?

At best, you can try holding a `WakeLock`. Your users will be angry with you if they feel that you are wasting their battery, though. And I am not certain that this works, either.

Comment: No, I have the same problem and its not that AccelerometerListener is accidentally unregistered. In a test I basically started the listener in my app service which logged all activity to a file, let the screen go to sleep, and shook the phone like crazy. Normally the log would fill up, doesn't when the screen goes to sleep. If I click the power button I get the lock screen. Shaking will log results, but the lock screen sleeps fast and it stopped monitoring the shakes again.

Answer (score 0):

You should check `onPause()`, `onStop()`, and `onDestroy()` methods and make sure that they do not contain any unregister of the sensor service.